# Given a module name atom, how can I create the struct for that module?

Tags: elixir

I want to go from `MyMod` to `%MyMod{}` in order to keep backwards compatibility with an older configuration format in a library I'm making.

The module is already defined and calls the `defstruct` macro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Kernel` function [`struct/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) should work fine:

```
struct(MyMod)   # => %MyMod{}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to look in kernel. Thank you.